# Which string metric or NLP algorithm is should I use to find substring in different URLs

Tags: python, string, url

I am trying to find URLs which have user provided keywords.

```
Eg. Keyword - 'Avengers' 
#URL1: www.xyzmovies.com/Avengers_2019/243564
#URL2: www.avengers.org/4r43435
#URL3: www.abcmovies.co/23543/avenngers_34435/walt/marvel/comics
```

Difficulty is that URL does not have single standard, keywords can come anywhere in the urls. Need to catch url which have spelling mistakes too.

Which algorithm would be best to do this task in python.

Comment: That task seems to be fit for using regular expression with `re` in python.

Comment: How bad are the spelling mistakes?

Comment: `'avengers' in url` is the test to check whether `'avengers'` is in the url.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can just use

```
"keyword".lower() in url.lower()
```

That will return True if the keyword is in the URL and False otherwise. The .lower() ensures that the result is not case sensitive. To account for typos, I would check out [stringgrouper](https://pypi.org/project/string-grouper/) or [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) libraries. Fuzzywuzzy's partial ratio would be well-suited for this because it looks specifically at partial string matches, so your keyword "Avengers" would be considered a perfect match to URL1, whereas "Avnegers" would likely still have a high score.